# Cant assign Future <String> function output to a String variable

Tags: flutter

I have a function "getName" that returns Future String

```
Future<String> getName(userID) async {
  CollectionReference collectionReference =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Users");
  QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await collectionReference.get();
  querySnapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
    if (element.get("ID") == userID) {
      print("returning ${element.get("Name")}"); >>>>That returns the right name when I test
      return element.get("Name");
    }
  });
  return "";
}
```

I want String variable "userName" to be assigned with the output of getName() so I did try it with two ways:

1- Using await

```
String userName = await getName(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);
  print(userName);
```

**Output**

```
I/flutter ( 5882): returning Maurice
I/flutter ( 5882):
```

2- Using .then

```
String userName = "";
  getName(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).then((value) {
    userName = value;
  });
  print(userName);
```

**Output**

```
I/flutter ( 5882): returning Maurice
I/flutter ( 5882):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are returning in the function that is inside the foreach.

to solve it try

```
Future<String> getName(userID) async {
  String name = "";
  CollectionReference collectionReference =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Users");
  QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await collectionReference.get();
  querySnapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
    if (element.get("ID") == userID) {
      print(
          "returning ${element.get("Name")}"); //>>>>That returns the right name when I test
      name = '${element.get("Name")}';
    }
  });
  return name;
}
```

I also recommend that you change forEach to:
for (var element in querySnapshot.docs)
and put a break; inside the if